# Error uninitialized constant CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

NameError in ExpenseReportsController#index

uninitialized constant CarrierWave

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

Not sure how to fix this error...

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave
http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with same error and I was using only https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64 this gem. Once I put 
gem 'carrierwave' to my Gemfile too, everything worked. Maybe this will help.